# Load Page to Iframe with using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I got Page  work with parameter and ı want to show it in iframe. however when ı set to iframe location my iframe not load all javascript. Normally Page works. My ıframe was working too. but now it is not working.
why?

```
 window.frames["MyFrame"].location = "Component/Component.php?pagename="+$(Element).attr("page-name");
```

it is my javascript code for set iframe location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`src` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-src) :

```
window.frames["MyFrame"].src = //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('MyFrame').src="Component/Component.php?pagename="+$(Element).attr("page-name");
```